# Dynamodb calculating item size

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I want to write a method which will calculate the `size` of the `Dynamodb item`. I checked Boto3 documentation but didn't find any equivalent Pre-built method.

**Can any one suggest a solution for this?**

Comment: can you define size?

Comment: actual size of the DynamoDB item like the size of item in BYTES or KILOBYTES

Answer (score 3):

Check out this handy calculator to estimate item size: https://zaccharles.github.io/dynamodb-calculator/

It tells you the item size *and* calculates the number of WCUs/RCUs to write/read from DynamoDB.

Comment: Is there any `method` to calculate the `size` of an `item`? I want to include a `method` in my project so if `item` reaches `max limit` i can use some sort of truncating mechanism to truncate that item.

Comment: @siva I am not aware of any tooling that supports calculating item sizes on-the-fly.  The The total size of an item is the sum of the lengths of its attribute names and values, so I suppose you could write such method yourself.  The AWS docs give some guidance on this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/CapacityUnitCalculations.html

Comment: Basically i am using `python`'s 1. __sizeof__() and 2. sys.getsizeof() methods. can i use any of these method to calculate the Dynamodb `item size`

Comment: Those methods seem like a good place to start, but I'm no python expert.  The DynamoDB calcluator I linked is in github, you can check out the implementation here: https://github.com/zaccharles/dynamodb-calculator/blob/master/index.html#L154.  It's in Javascript, but the conversion to python should be fairly straightforward.